# Printing filenames in a directory in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

Say I'm in a directory and there's another directory called pictures with .jpg images inside that I want to run an operation on say "./operation image1.jpg" how can I do this for every jpg in the directory pictures? When I searched for iterating through files in a directory I could not get the output I wanted.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd pictures
pictures=$ls

for pic in $pictures
do
   ./operation $pic
done
```

That's the code I have. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `operation` accepts multiple file arguments, maybe you could simply do `operation pictures/*.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `ls` to get the list of files, since that won't work well with spaces inside file names. It turns something like:

```
my file.jpg
another file.jpg
```

into:

```
my
file.jpg
another
file.jpg
```

Let `bash` handle the fil list and you won't run into that problem. Just remember to quote each file so that those with spaces in them are preserved whole:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd pictures
for pic in *.jpg ; do 
    ./operation "$pic"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
find pictures/ -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec \./operation {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that spaces in filenames would cause problems, your script would work, but your pictures=$ls assignment is incorrect. It should be pictures=$(ls)... If you ever need to consider whitespace in a variable, put double-quotes around it: "$var" ... Also, don't use ls as your source of filenames; it has many problems which other methods avoid; eg, use find or shell expansion as shown in paxdiablo's answer.

`find` gives great control over what you actually list and even how you process it.

Here are a couple more ways to do it.

```
# using find
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec ./operation "{}" \;

# using an array
pic=(*.jpg)
for p in "${pic[@]}" ;do
  ./operation "$p"
done

# You can (with care) even use ls ... but why would you?  
# I've just added it here to show the use of IFS (Input Field Seperator)
IFS=$'\n'  # this makes `\n` the only delimiter.
pic=$(ls -1 *.jpg )
for p in $pic ;do
  ./operation "$p"
done
```

Comment: FWIW, using "{}" in find does not make any difference, because "{}" is expanded by bash and {} is expanded by find, in that order. find will expand {} as a single argument, spaces in file name don't matter.